# One Layout file instead of many similar ones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, imagebutton

I have several (for about 10 activities) XML layout files that all look quite similar. Here you can see one of them:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/container_frame_softrdinks"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        android:layout_width="432dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:background="#435cb53f"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_CocktailSelectionActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Softdrinks" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_mainActivity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton2"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton3"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton3"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_1" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton5"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton7"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton5"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton7"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton7"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton9"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton11"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton9"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageButton14"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton11"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageButton13"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageButton11"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_dish_2" />



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>




    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now the question is whether it is possible (and advicable ) to have only one XML-layout file for all of the different activities. I personally see the following problems:

1. The number of bottoms are not identical in every layout file. Since I am using a ScrollView inside of a ConstraintLayout, I would not know how to disgn the layout. I have to set the constraints manually in the XML layout file for all the ImageButtoms
2. I am not using normal Buttoms but ImageButtons in every XML layout file. When creating the XML layout file I have to specify the pictures being displayed on the ImageButtons. I do not know how to do this dynamically

So I'd be happy for every comment and I would really appreciate your help.

Does nobody have an idea if that is possible and how to do something like this?

Comment: if you're fine with how things are currently, why waste time and effort to make it more complicated :) if you have a lot of similar layouts and it'll be easier to slightly modify each of them to fit a feature, then it's going to be faster to do that, probably. if you want fewer files and a (potentially) more complicated approach to managing layouts, then try make it generic. there isn't a right or a wrong answer here, it's going to be based on opinion

Comment: Thanks localNobody for your comment. Yes you are right. But still I would like to know if that is possible and how it would be possible to have only one generic layout. I mentioned the 2 problems that I see and it would be quite intersting for me to see how to solve these issues with just one layout. Of course, after having understood what and how to do it is totally up to me, whether I will really use the 'new' approach in my app. Futher, as I want to improve my programming capabilities, I would really like to learn new concepts. This is why I'd highly appreciate answers to my posted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Stuff to your Layout and manage parameters of your layouts completely at runtime (most often done in OnCreate or OnCreateView (depends wether it's Activity or Fragment)
Just do a base Layout with the AppBar etc and add the image buttons by code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220554/discussion-on-answer-by-torge-rosendahl-one-layout-file-instead-of-many-similar).

Comment: --> Hi Torge, can you look at the chat. I have a question to discuss. Unfortunately the comments were locked in your answer and you do not get notified when I write something in the chat. Maybe comments should be allowed again such that you get notified.

Comment: Thanks Torge for your effort and help. I have updated the code in the forum again. There are some aspects that do not look good (see screenshot in the chat). I appreciate any further comment from you and I am quite thankful for your help.